# How to pass parameters to controller in FastRoute?

Tags: php, regex, lumen, fastroute

I did not find anything related to **Lumen** (not Laravel) for passing value to controller. Is my approach wrong or am I just missing the obvious ?

I want to pass a parameter to controller, not talking about the `{name}` in `localhost:8000/someprefix/{name}`. As lumen is using **FastRoute** and I do not want to change back to default router. I want to pass value to the controller as method parameter ? Any help will be appreciated.

*web.php*

```
// $value has the method
// I want to pass the $myParameter value to below mentioned statement ?
// and receive it as parameter in **methodNotAllowedHere()** in the controller
$myParameter = 10;
$router->addRoute($value, '/signup', 'UserController@methodNotAllowedHere');
```

*UserController.php*

```
// i want to receive $myParameter as  $value 
public function methodNotAllowedHere( $value = '' ) {
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your purpose a little bit more? Why you're not defining a global variable or add new environment variable?

Comment: I'm creating an API ( like you don't already know :p ). I just want to pass what kind of request it is `['POST','PUT','PATCH']` etc and return an JSON response including the response something like `{'request_method': 'POST'}` but extracted from passed parameter.